# MSVC inline assembly to GCC (with parameter and return)

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline

```
inline float sqrt2(float sqr)
{
    float root = 0;

    __asm
    {
    sqrtss xmm0, sqr
    movss root, xmm0
    }

    return root;
}
```

here is MSVC compilator inline assembly which I want to compile with gcc x86, what I know that gcc inline assembly is getting called with asm("asm here"); but I completely don't know how to include parameter in that, the result is obtained by "=r" I know only.

Which should result in something like that:

```
asm("sqrtss xmm0, %1\n\t"
        "movss %0, xmm0"
        : "=r" (root)
        : "r" (sqr));
```

Comment: Do you really need this? the stdlib version should automatically be turned into this by the compiler.

Comment: This is the simplest example I have. Of course I can change that into standard sqrt but thats method is faster. I have more assembly to convert so I want to learn on this one

Comment: Before trying to outsmart the compiler with assembly code, you might want to read this example: [More efficient assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509578/more-efficient-assembly-code)

Comment: @kermitesea I'd be almost willing to bet the [compiler can beat your assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9601427/332733) in almost all cases on -O2. In the cases it can't I would highly suggest profiling first before resorting to assembly.

Answer (score 3):

The `r` constraint is for general purpose registers. `x` is for `xmm`. Consult the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) for more details. Also, if you are using a `mov` in inline asm, you are likely doing it wrong.

```
inline float sqrt2(float sqr)
{
    float root = 0;

    __asm__("sqrtss %1, %0" : "=x" (root) : "x" (sqr));

    return root;
}
```

Note that gcc is entirely capable of generating `sqrtss` instruction from `sqrtf` library function call. You may use `-fno-math-errno` to get rid of some minor error checking overhead.

Comment: Thanks so much for very strong informations. Definitely gonna check manual ty :)

Comment: Note that if you want to use the native FMA functions in GCC clang that come as part of AVX and AVX2 you need to do the `-mfma` flag. Then the compiler will gladly replace `std::fma` with the appropriate instruction